# Can there be no 'a' between such and a noun?

Tags: articles, comparative-constructions

> When it comes to losing weight, a quick fix to would be nice, but we
>   know there’s no **such [a]** thing.
>  ([Aussie 7 News](http://audioscraps.tistory.com/157))

It sounds like there isn’t ‘a’ in the news. So I wonder if it be right when there is no ‘a’ after ‘such.’ Would it be okay?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is easy to stumble over because the construction without a negative, *such a thing*, is anomalous.

Any word you might substitute for *such*—a word which plays the same syntactic role, such as *similar* or *like* or *different* or *other*—**follows** the article: *a similar thing*, *a like thing*, *a different thing*, *another thing*. And historically, in fact, *a such thing* alternated freely with *such a thing* before the language decided it preferred the *such a* construction about 1400.

Once you realize that the underlying sense is *a such*, the proper negative becomes clear: *no* replaces *a* as the determiner, and reverts to its normal position: *no similar thing*, *no like thing*, *no different thing*, *no other thing*—and *no such thing*.

But your instinct is shared by many native speakers. The construction *such a thing* is so firmly fixed on people's tongues that you will frequently hear people say *no such a thing*. And at least in my own native dialect the struggle to make syntactic sense of the construction results in *no such **of a** thing*.

Comment: Thanks for your excellent answer. Does 1400 means 1400 A.D.?

Comment: @RobertH Yes it does.